# Pointer Unboxing in Python

Tags: c#, python, .net, pointers, python.net

Good Afternoon,

I have a class from a third party DLL with the following Buffer.Attach method:
`public void Attach( byte* aBuffer, uint aSize)`

The method can be called from C# using:
`aBuffer.Attach( (byte*) arrPointer , nBytes)`
where arrPointer is a System.Reflection.Pointer

How can I call the method using Python.Net. If I pass only the arrPointer to the method I receive a TypeError: No method matches given arguments.

In other word, how can I perform the pointer unboxing in python?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Best Regards,

Brice